# Sequential characterization of closedness, and completeness of a set.

Tags: calculus

After reading the theroem about [Sequential characterization of closedness of the set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153355/sequential-characterization-of-closedness-of-the-set), and the definition of a complete set(*a metric space is said to be complete if every Cauchy sequence has its limit in the space X* ), I can't undertand what's the difference between both claimings.

Comment: It's hard to guess what statements you are referring to. In order for your question to be answerable, you should include the full statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the claims are these:

- $S$ is closed if whenever a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $S$ converges, $\lim_nx_n\in S$;
- $S$ is complete if every Cauchy sequence of elements of $S$ converges to an element of $S$.

The difference is that in the case of closed sets we are assuming that the sequence is *convergent*, whereas in the case of complete sets we are assuming that the sequence is a *Cauchy* sequence. These are distinct assumptions.

Comment: Yes, but I think that Cauchy sequences and convergent sequences are the same, aren't they?

Comment: @Leire In a non-complete metric space, they're different.  For example, in $(0, 1)$, the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is Cauchy but it has no limit in the metric space $(0, 1)$.

Comment: There is a theorem that gives a relationship, though: A subset of a **complete** metric space is closed if and only if it is complete.

Comment: Worth also noting that closeness is a relative property (of $S$ within whatever metric space $X\supset S$ you are looking at) - you cannot decide if $S$ is closed without knowing $X$. (For example, if you take $S$ itself as a metric space, it is *always* closed "in itself".) On the other hand, completeness is an *intrinsic* property of $S$ - doesn't matter whether it is taken "in itself" or as a subset of a bigger metric space.

Comment: @user8734617 That's a nice remark. That is connected to the fact that, given a sequence, being a Cauchy sequence is an intrinsic property, whereas being convergent is not.